# Getting an file.png image to display on a frame using java.awt and java.swing

Tags: java, image, swing, awt

Im trying to get an image to display on a frame for a game Im creating. Rather than extend any JPanels or JFrame, I just create multiple frame classes and one action class.Im currently having trouble getting an image to display on a test frame I created. My code compiles but when I click on the frame it shuts down. Thanks!

P.S this is only part of my code. I heard its not good to post total code online.

Code:

```
    public void testframe(){
    testframe = new Frame("Main Menu");
    testframe.setSize(1600,1600);
    try{
        myPicture = ImageIO.read(new File("basic.png"));
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();

        //FirstFrame.setVisible(true);
        //testframe.setVisible(false);
    }

    JLabel picLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(myPicture));

    testframe.add(picLabel);

    //testframe.drawImage(myPicture,"png", );

    testframe.setVisible(true);

}

private void showButtonDemo(){

    Font myFont = new Font("Serif", Font.ITALIC | Font.BOLD, 12);
    Font newFont = myFont.deriveFont(50F);
    headerLabel.setText("SNAKE GAME"); 
    headerLabel.setFont(newFont);
    statusLabel.setText("By Tejas and Ashwin");
    statusLabel.setFont(newFont);

    Button startButton = new Button("Start Game");//begins game
    Button snakecolorButton = new Button("Choose Snake Color");//selects snake color
    Button themeColorButton = new Button("Choose Theme");//selects two colors(1 primary and 1 secondary)
    Button InstructionsButton = new Button("Instructions");
    Button testbutton = new Button("test");

    testbutton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            //testframe();
            //testframe.setVisible(true);
            FirstFrame.setVisible(false);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Post a [mcve] for best help.

Comment: Why are you using AWT components such as Frame and Button *with* Swing components?

Comment: It was easier for me, because I didn't fully understand all of the Swing and AWT components. Is this not a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example? How should I add?

Comment: @airbmx Can we compile and run the code?  Where is the image stored?  Is it included in the project or is it external?

Comment: Please read the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) link

Comment: Swing component names start with `J` (`JFrame`, `JButton`, etc.). AWT components (`Frame`, `Button`, etc.) are much older and generally shouldn't be used anymore.

Answer (score 0):

First, Sharing code is needed for help so if you think the code in anyway involes what you need help with share it, else wise it doesnt matter...
For the question at hand, You can use a jlable and set a iamge for it to display a png but the BEST way to do this would be to create this for a game would be to create a class (Player for example) and a render method, On render you display the image at the loc (XYZ) of the player,

```
ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Name\\Pictures\\image.png");
    JLabel imageLabel = new JLabel(image); 
    frame.add(imageLabel);
```

Remember to set it as visible and  set its bounds,

Comment: *"Remember to set it as visible"* That is only needed for top level windows such as `JFrame` and should be done after all components have been added and `pack()` has been called *"and set its bounds"* ..and setting the bounds is ***rarely if ever*** advisable.